# Should I Prune Determinate Tomato Plants?

Tags: pruning, tomatoes

If determinate tomato plants are leggy, should they be pruned or not? Is it ever too late to pulled and planted deeper?

Comment: More information please - how long have you had these plants, are they in pots, indoors or outdoors, or in the ground? Photo could be useful... as would your location, or part of the world.

Comment: I might dig up and plant deeper. "Pulling" and planting deeper seems rather needlessly abusive. If they are in pots, just plant deeper when they are next repotted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't prune determinates. If they are anywhere close to pushing out buds, then you'll lose all those tomatoes.